# Update state and fetch data onclick (with state hook)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to (by interaction with the form) update :

- A state of an object (the new value of the form)
- Fetch data to send it to DB by (Django) REST

Here's the form :

```
<form className="form1">
    <h2>Select your theme</h2>
    <select name="theme" onChange={e => submit(e)} value={theme}>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Dark">Dark</option>
        <CSRFToken/>
    </select>
</form>
```

The event :

```
const [theme, setTheme] = useState(results.theme)

  // function submit(e) {
  const submit = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let out = e.target.value

      setTheme(out)

      fetch("/api-out/5_settings", {
          credentials: 'include',
          method: 'PATCH',
          mode: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              theme
          }),
      }).then((response) => {
          console.log(out)
          console.log(theme)
          console.log(response)
          return response
      })
    }
```

My code works but when I switch option in the form (from dark to white), the state change but the data is not sent to the API because the theme is undefined. It works after when I switch again.

I see some answers like :

```
setTheme({...theme, out})
```

But I don't understand and not sure if it fits my problem and if it's a recent solution.

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to come from the asynchronous nature of React state updates: when you call `setTheme(out)`, `theme` is not updated immediately with the value of `out`, it will be updated later for the next render.

Thus, if you update a state in a function and you need that value **during the same synchronous function call** to do something else, use the value directly instead of relying on the state value. In your case you should send you request to the backend with:

```js
body: JSON.stringify({
              out
          }),
```

And not

```js
body: JSON.stringify({
              theme
          }),
```

You can read more on React state update asynchronous behavior on the [React FAQ about State](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't know why but if I put "theme" I have a status 202 (good) but it's not updated.
setState and setTheme is the same (for adaptation) ?